# Windows Filtering Platform - Unresolved External Symbols

Tags: c, windows, linker-errors, windows-kernel, wfp

I have writing a Windows Filtering Platform (WFP) kernel driver and I am trying to add some callouts.

I am using some `FWPM_LAYER` GUIDs, such as

```
FWPM_LAYER_OUTBOUND_TRANSPORT_V4
FWPM_LAYER_OUTBOUND_TRANSPORT_V6
FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V4
FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V6
```

However I am getting unresolved external symbols when using these.

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _FWPM_LAYER_OUTBOUND_TRANSPORT_V4
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _FWPM_LAYER_OUTBOUND_TRANSPORT_V6
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V4
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V6
```

I am using the following headers

```
#define NDIS61 1

#include <ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>

#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4201)
#include <fwpsk.h>
#pragma warning(pop)

#include <fwpmk.h>
#include <fwpvi.h>
#include <guiddef.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <devguid.h>
```

And I am linking against the following additional dependencies.

```
$(DDK_LIB_PATH)wdmsec.lib
$(DDK_LIB_PATH)fwpkclnt.lib
```

I am unable to find what I am missing, it appears that those GUIDs are located within `fwmpk.h` which is in the `Fwpkclnt.lib` library, which I am building against.

Comment: you need `#include <initguid.h>` **before** `#include <fwpmk.h>`

Comment: @RbMm that solved it, thank you. Do you want to add it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered by [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656) in the comments, the solution was to move the `#include <initguid.h>` statement **before** the `include <fwmpk.h>` statement.

```
#define NDIS61 1

#include <ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>

#include <guiddef.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <devguid.h>

#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4201)
#include <fwpsk.h>
#pragma warning(pop)

#include <fwpmk.h>
#include <fwpvi.h>
```